# Why stdout.write() is not working in Terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am novice in **Node JS**.

I am trying to test **cURL** request on my `localhost:3000` port. I am using **Sublime Text 4** text editor. **cURL** request on Windows Terminal works fine but Loading Bar is not showing up in terminal. Instead it is showing up in *Sublime Text Console*.

[image: Sublime Text Console]

Here's Terminal Output without loading bar

[image: Windows Terminal Output]

I've tried the following code :

```
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const processes = require("process");
const rdl = require("readline");

class LoadingBar {
    constructor(size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.cursor = 0;
        this.timer = null;
    }
    start() {
        processes.stdout.write("\x1B[?25l");
        processes.stdout.write("[");
        for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            processes.stdout.write("-");
        }
        processes.stdout.write("]");
        this.cursor = 1;
        rdl.cursorTo(processes.stdout, this.cursor, 0);
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            processes.stdout.write("#");
            this.cursor++;
            if (this.cursor >= this.size) {
                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                processes.stdout.write("\x1B[?25h");
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}

const loader = new LoadingBar(25);

const obj = {
    "Response": 200,
    "Operation": 'successful',
};

app.get("/response", (req, res) => {
    loader.start();
    res.json(obj);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

I want to make cURL request from Terminal and after that Loading Bar will show up and then I will get the `obj`. But for some reasons `stdout.write()` is not working in Terminal. What should I do?